# DELETE in [validating two fields]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I (and I find) seeking ways to validate two fields with a DELETE.

I.e. `DELETE FROM X_Table WHERE IDRESERVA IN (.........)`, it might work, but there SERIES associated with the same numbers,
and the likelihood of more things eliminate me accurate, is 100%. Possessing different SERIES, Different Numbers.

```
Ie BAAO/300. CAAO/300.
```

With the above statement, I deleted two records, and from above I just wanted to eliminate: BAAO/300.

I was looking for something like:

```
DELETE FROM X_Table WHERE IDRESERVA AND SERIE IN (.........)
```

Or if there otherwise would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is right, but it's not SQL valid, 
You can use the following valid statement:

```
Delete from X_Table WHERE IDRESERVA in (...) and SERIE IN (....)
```

Comment: If friend. Now I remember, I tried performing well and did not work. Since there is no way to recognize who is the Series or the ID for each series.

I tried as well and began to clear the entire DB (test).

Without further ado;

Grateful for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
DELETE FROM X_Table WHERE (IDRESERVA,SERIE) IN (('BAAO',300), ('CAAO',400), ...)
```

which is not supported in SQL Server unfortunately. (In Oracle it is, and it makes some queries very readable, which would not be otherwise.)

So you are left with

```
DELETE FROM X_Table 
WHERE (IDRESERVA = 'BAAO' AND SERIE = 300)
OR    (IDRESERVA = 'CAAO' AND SERIE = 400)
OR    ...
```